# What test to use? Splitting up dataset -> increase performance value

Tags: dataset

I am working on my thesis and I have collected some data. Now I need to know what kind of test I should use.

I have an algorithm with which I produce a bunch of data over a dataset. Then I calculate the mrr (mean reciprocal rank) value from it. So I have one value that represents the performance of my algorithm over the dataset.

Then I split up the dataset in two smaller datasets (not randomly) and I calculate the mrr again for those two. Now I want to verify that the increase or decrease in mrr is no coincidence, that it is significant.

Any idea what I should use?

Thanks

(I did have a statistics class but what I really missed there is learning how to find the right test)

EDIT:
Ok so more details. I am doing research on the influence of bad singing on query by humming systems. In such system people can hum a tune and receive a list of songs that might match that tune. 
So for every query (humming) in the dataset I calculate the place (the rang) of the original song in the returned list. Of this I can calculate the mrr, which indicates the performance of the algorithm.
Then I split up the dataset in good and bad singers and I want to know if the change in mrr for these subsets is valid.

I want to proof that bad singers would have a harder time finding their song than good singers.

Comment: I think some more background could be helpful. It seems to be that what you actually want is to show that the way you split the data is helpful? If so, you could compare with random splits.

Comment: @Erik: I added some more details. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Is there a strict distinction between "good" and "bad" singers? Or do you have some more-or-less continuous scale of how "good" a singer is? Also, is there some reason why you use the calculated "mrr" rather than the rank of the original song in the returned list as the measure of having a "harder time" to find a song?

Comment: Good and bad is a strict distinction. And I use the mrr because this is a measurement over a set and not a single song.